# Selecting Image from image gallery works on emulator but not the android devices

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to select image from the image gallery of android phone and it runs as expected in the emulator but when I install it in my galaxy s4 and runit, it doesn't work. I have installed the cordova camera plugin and running cordova 3.5.0.2.4 The code snippet is as below

upload.html

```
    <button class="button-positive button-block button" ng-click="PhotoLibrary()">Select Picture <i class="ion-android-image"></i></button>

 <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-image">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <img id="smallimage" size="10" />                    
                </div>
            </div>            
         </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="UploadPicture()" class="button-positive button-block button">Upload<i class="ion-paper-airplane margin"></i></button>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.PhotoLibrary = function (){
            $scope.image = document.getElementById('smallimage');
            if (navigator.camera){
                 navigator.camera.getPicture( photoSuccess, photoError,
                     {     quality: 50,
                         sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
                         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                        }

                       );
                } else {
                    alert('camera not found');
                }
            };

         function photoSuccess(imageURI) {
            if (imageURI.substring(0,21)=="content://com.android") {
              var photo_split=imageURI.split("%3A");
              imageURI="content://media/external/images/media/"+photo_split[1];
            }
            $scope.imageURI = imageURI
            $scope.image.src = $scope.imageURI;
            $scope.apply();

}
function photoError(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

It works fine in the emulator and I can access the image gallery but it doesnt work in the real devices though and whenever I click on the button to select the image, it alerts me 'camera not found' . Does anyone know why it happens?? Is it related to cordova camera plugin?? Or am i doing something wrong? Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Check in your settings and see if your app has permission to take pictures

Comment: hey James, I have added all the necessary permission in the manifest file. This problem only occurs whenever I try upload the source code to PhoneGap and run the application. However, it work fine whenever I run the app in the emulator or on the device using cordova run android command.

Comment: Then it's likely to be a hardware specific problem. Have you tried on other android devices?

Comment: yeah I have tried on different devices as well but still not working.. and I have no idea why and I can't seem to find any error on logcat as well..